# Array to List or List to Array, which conversion is faster?

Tags: java, arrays, list, casting, type-conversion

In java, basically these two conversions are so common and popular...

- Array to List

  `List<String> list = Arrays.asList(array);`
- List to Array

  `String[] array = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);`

So the question is, which is faster, Array to List or its reverse?

Now, Why am I asking this question? Because I've to implement a method in which an array or a list, both can be passed in parameter. I just have to iterate this list and that's all. So here I have to decide that what should I convert? array to list or list to array!

Comment: That's not type casting.

Comment: Why don't you run a benchmark on your own?

Comment: It's conversion, and it doesn't matter one bit which is faster. You should use whichever fits the design better. You can even implement both.

Comment: Beware of *premature optimization*
**Never** choose a certain syntax or style for *performance consideration* unless you have **proven by measurement** that you actually *have* a performance problem **and** the code in question is really the bottleneck **and** the alternative *really solves the problem.*

Comment: @Kayaman I have updated the question. If still it is wrong, then please update.

Comment: No need to down vote, if i am completely wrong, then tell me, I will delete the question.

Comment: It really doesn't matter which one you choose. It certainly doesn't matter enough to waste time on.

Comment: Its not that you are completely wrong, this question just could be solved by yourself just running your code and checking whats faster.

Comment: @TomBombadil that would require him to know how to create a proper microbenchmark, which isn't that easy. SO is filled with questions where wrong benchmarks are used to draw wrong conclusions, but this question doesn't need to be one of them.

Comment: If I have to do it myself, then why am I asking it here! I just want to get benefit of your experience man. It's 20 years in java. :)

Comment: @Kayaman You are right. Actually i don't think it will even have a  noticible effect...

Comment: Finally, @yole has answered the question. And downvoters can see, it was not an worthless question.

Comment: If you are concerned about performance, note that `list.toArray(new String[0]);` is faster than `list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);`.

Comment: @Khan: yole has given a good answer to the question you have asked. It does not mean that conversion to a `List` is always what to do when a method can accept a List or an array. Other elements can matter...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Arrays.asList` is faster because it does not copy data - it returns an object wrapping the array passed to it, and implementing the `List` interface. `Collection.toArray()` copies the data to the array, so it runs in O(N) instead of O(1).

Comment: Added note: This does not necessarily mean the OP's code will be faster. OP mentions that they already accept two overloads, an Array and a List. OP would need to gather data on how often each overload is called to determine if transforming to a List would be faster. If %99.99 use the Array overload you might want to stick with the array implementation

Comment: Are you really sure that doing intensive random access on a LinkedList will be better than converting it first to an array?

Comment: yole answered the question exactly. `Arrays.asList` is the (theoretically) faster method. Whether it is the **right** way to go for a special use-case is a completely other question.

Comment: `ArrayList` copies data using `System.arraycopy`. I don't think that it would be *observably* slower.

Comment: For the majority of questions asked on SO about performance, there won't be any _observable_ difference between the options considered by OP. However, when there's an essential difference in behavior which has a performance impact, it's still useful to highlight and understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays.asList will faster since it doesnt have to copy any data instead it has to just pack it.

Comment: Pack?  There is no "packing" going on here.  Perhaps you mean "wrap"?

Comment: yup thats true!!

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you are handling the rod the wrong side. The good question to ask is whether you need an array or List in your method. By the way, `List` it just an interface, and many implementations could exist. For example the JDK directly provides `ArrayList` which is backed by an array, so conversion to array should be fast, and `LinkedList` which is a doubly linked implementation, and many others including abstract classes intended to help for custom implementations.

In short, **you** know how you want to use the elements in your method, so just use the more appropriate *container*.

In my opininion, if you intend to iterate the elements, use a `List`, if you need intensive random access and could receive an linked list implementation, then use an Array.

Comment: `ArrayList.toArray()` still performs a copy, so it still runs in O(N), even though `ArrayList` is indeed backed by an array.

Comment: @yole You are right. I just meant that the conversion time was not necessarily the more important. Maybe I have tried to answer the question OP should have asked and not the one he actually asked ;-)